# RoR: devise, how to stop reccording the ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise in order to handle the authentification of my users but i don't need to record the ip address.
I can't find a way to custom devise to stop tracking the IP, is there a solution ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They advise overriding the IP related methods on your resource](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4849#issuecomment-534733131)

If you still want to track sessions, but not IPs, the easiest way I've found is to simply override the IP related methods on your resource (e.g. `User`):

```
  def current_sign_in_ip; end
  def last_sign_in_ip=(_ip); end
  def current_sign_in_ip=(_ip); end
```

This will allow enabling the :trackable module without any IP being saved

Comment: it's helpful to include examples, or extracts from the remote site.  there is no guarantee that the external website will be available in 6 months, in which case your answer would no longer work

Answer (score 0):

what devise version do you use?
since version `4.5.0` with this [pull request](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/4857/files) merged, you are now eligible to disable `:trackable` option in your model **User** for example.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # some devise options, but remove :trackable if you have already
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable
end
```